# The trouble about the JCR multi-valued property when using JCR_GET_BY_ID

Tags: java, apache-camel, jackrabbit, jcr

I'm using the `Apache Camle version 2.14.0` with `Apache Jackrabbit 2.8.0` and have found some trouble about the `camel-jcr` with `JCR_GET_BY_ID` when the node contains `multi-valued property` as the following: -

```
2014-09-26 10:19:21.604 [Client Event Poller] [] ERROR o.a.c.processor.DefaultErrorHandler
       - 215 log Failed delivery for (
      MessageId: ID-CharleeCh-53350-1411701537295-3-1 on 
      ExchangeId: ID-CharleeCh-53350-1411701537295-3-12). 
      Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: 
      javax.jcr.ValueFormatException: property /my-parent3/my-child31/myMuliple 
      is a multi-valued property, so it's values can only be retrieved as an array

Stacktrace
javax.jcr.ValueFormatException: property /my-parent3/my-child31/myMuliple 
    is a multi-valued property, so it's values can only be retrieved as an array
at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.server.ServerObject.getRepositoryException(ServerObject.java:139) ~[jackrabbit-jcr-rmi-2.8.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.server.ServerProperty.getValue(ServerProperty.java:62) ~[jackrabbit-jcr-rmi-2.8.0.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:275) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:252) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.server.ServerProperty_Stub.getValue(Unknown Source) ~[jackrabbit-jcr-rmi-2.8.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.client.ClientProperty.getValue(ClientProperty.java:164) ~[jackrabbit-jcr-rmi-2.8.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.camel.component.jcr.JcrProducer.process(JcrProducer.java:69) ~[camel-jcr-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
```

I also have a chance to investigate to the `camel-jcr` source code, the [org.apache.camel.component.jcr.JcrProducer](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jcr/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/jcr/JcrProducer.java), and found that it use the following:-

```java
        if (JcrConstants.JCR_INSERT.equals(operation)) {
            ...
            for (String key : headers.keySet()) {
                Value value = converter.convertTo(Value.class, 
                                                  exchange, 
                                                  message.getHeader(key));
                ...
            }
            ...
        } else if (JcrConstants.JCR_GET_BY_ID.equals(operation)) {
            ...
            while (properties.hasNext()) {
                Property property = properties.nextProperty();
                Class<?> aClass = classForJCRType(property);
                Object value = converter.convertTo(aClass, 
                                                   exchange, 
                                                   property.getValue());
                ...
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported operation: " + operation);
        }
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Since the code uses the `Value.class` and `property.getValue()` which is for the `non-multi-valued`. Does it mean that the `camel-jcr` does not provide the support to the `multi-valued`?

Do we have any workaround for supporting the multi-valued? At the moment I consider to replace the `JcrProducer` with my own interim fixing. Anyhow I thought that it may not be a proper way and would like your help to advise further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted to the [Camel User Group](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/camel-jcr-The-trouble-about-the-JCR-multi-valued-property-when-using-JCR-GET-BY-ID-td5757029.html) and found that it is a limitation for the current `camel-jcr:2.14.0`. I've fixed as the [pull request](https://github.com/apache/camel/pull/287).

I hope this may help other who faces the same issue.